# Как выровнять спрайт по центру?

Tags: css

Есть три круга, в этих трех кругах будет размещен спрайт(несколько иконок). Как их выровнять? если bg-position уже отведен под спрайт. И с размерами под иконки, выходит переопределение.

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.circle {
 width: 450px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle-img {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: yellow;
 /*background: url(img/sprites.png) no-repeat;*/
}

.green {
 /*width: 15px;
 height: 15px;*/
 background-color: green;
 background-position: 0 15px;
}

.red {
 /*width: 15px;
 height: 15px;*/
 background-color: red;
 background-position: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="circle">
  <a href="#" class="circle-img yellow"></a>
  <a href="#" class="circle-img green"></a>
  <a href="#" class="circle-img red"></a>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? Разве нельзя задать новый стиль для новых элементов? Или я не понял вопрос?

Comment: У тебя есть закрывающийся (!) тег `<a>`. В него пихать можешь чё угодно: спрайты, пепси, фанты - и так далее, и позиционировать как угодно относительно `circle-img`.

Comment: Так и сделал, добавив новый элемент. А без добавления элементов в разметку возможно такое реализовать? например с помощью псевдо-элементов или это уже костыли ?

Comment: При помощи псевдоэлементов — лучше всего, это не костыль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте псевдоэлементы для позиционирования иконок спрайта

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.circle {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle-img {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;   
}
.circle-img:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin: -7.5px 0 0 -7.5px;
    background-image: url(img/sprites.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
.circle-img.yellow:before {    
    background-color: orange;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.circle-img.green:before {    
    background-color: green;
    background-position: 0 15px;
}
.circle-img.red:before {    
    background-color: red;
    background-position: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <a href="#" class="circle-img yellow"></a>
    <a href="#" class="circle-img green"></a>
    <a href="#" class="circle-img red"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Указывайте вместо `background: url(img/sprites.png) no-repeat;` свойство `background-image: url('../img/sprites.png');` и `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: это неправильная запись background-image: url(img/sprites.png) no-repeat;

Comment: @soledar10 cкопипастил и не глянул.

Comment: Почему, скажешь хоть?

Comment: Я вот могу привести аргумент в пользу того, что нужно всё в одном свойстве указывать. То же самое касается сокращений свойств для фона, бордеров и так далее. А ты?

Comment: @VostokSisters я согласен. Ответ дал с учетом наглядности.

Comment: Ну это совет тогда, а не ответ, можно было комментом обойтись)

Comment: @VostokSisters это ответ на вопрос, почему перебивается свойство. Участник не знал такого свойства, как background-image.

Comment: А-а, понятно тогда.