# Css спрайт, вылезает соседняя картинка. Что можно сделать

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гуру.

Имеется менюшка (`li ul`) с порядка 30 пунктами, дизайн адаптивный (резиновый). Соответственно указать "не переносить текст" возможности нет.

Изначально каждая картинка грузилась для меню отдельно, но 60 запросов к серверу каждый раз это реальная нагрузка, потому то я решил перенести меню в спрайт.

И возникла проблема

Если у пунктов, которые состоят из одного слова проблем нет, то у пунктов в несколько слов при переносе становится виден соседний элемент картинки. 
Особая проблема возникает через просмотра сайта через Opera Mini, там даже пункт меню из двух строк переносится, что при водит к такому отображению:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="b-menu" >
<div>Меню</div>
<ul>
<li class="r1">
        <a href="" title="">Первое меню</a>
    </li>
<li class="r2">
        <a href="" title="">новое меню и интересное и просто проверка</a>
    </li>
<li class="r3">
        <a href="" title="">Тестовое меню</a>
    </li>
<li class="r4">
        <a href="" title="">Главная</a>
    </li>


</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

.b-menu {
        background: url(***.png) repeat;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 18px;
        padding-bottom: 6px
    }

    .b-menu li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 41%;
        padding: 8px 0px 2px 25px;
        line-height: 12px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        background-image: url(http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0317/38/7ccbd2677eba885ee4e2c1ea8ed46738.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .b-menu li:nth-child(2n+2) {
        width: 100px;
    }
    .b-menu li a {
        color: #777;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 14px;
    }

    .b-menu .r1 {
    background-position: -7px 2px;
    }
    .b-menu li.r1:hover {
    background-position: -7px -28px;
    }

    .b-menu li.r2 {
    background-position: -7px -61px;
    }
    .b-menu li.r2:hover {
    background-position: -7px -91px;
    }

    .b-menu li.r3 {
    background-position: -7px -123px;
    }
    .b-menu li.r3:hover {
    background-position: -7px -153px;
    }

    .b-menu li.r4 {
    background-position: -7px -179px;
    }
    .b-menu li.r4:hover {
    background-position: -7px -209px;
    }
```

Как то можно исправить? Пример живого кода меню я разместил тут https://jsfiddle.net/c9pkmjo3/ . Я знаю HTML на любительском уровне.. может что забыл указать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выровнять спрайт по центру?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624764/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таком случае стоит картинки перенести в отдельный элемент. 
Например так:

```
.b-menu li{
    ...
    position:relative;
 }
.b-menu li:before{
      content:'';
      position:absolute;
      left:0;right:0;
      height:20px;
      width:20px;
      background-image: url(http://i91.fastpic.ru/....png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Чуть ниже пояснили на примере кода как надо :-) Это просто я из-за недостатка знаний и опыта не понял что на что надо было изменить.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.b-menu {
  background: url(***.png) repeat;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 6px
}
  
.b-menu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 41%;
  padding: 8px 0px 2px 25px;
  line-height: 12px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: relative;

}
  
.b-menu li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0317/38/7ccbd2677eba885ee4e2c1ea8ed46738.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
  
.b-menu li:nth-child(2n+2) {
  width: 100px;
}

.b-menu li a {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

.b-menu .r1:before {
  background-position: -7px 2px;
}
.b-menu li.r1:hover:before {
  background-position: -7px -28px;
}

.b-menu li.r2:before {
  background-position: -7px -61px;
}
.b-menu li.r2:hover:before {
  background-position: -7px -91px;
}

.b-menu li.r3:before {
  background-position: -7px -123px;
}
.b-menu li.r3:hover:before {
  background-position: -7px -153px;
}

.b-menu li.r4:before {
  background-position: -7px -179px;
}
.b-menu li.r4:hover:before {
  background-position: -7px -209px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-menu" >
  <div>Меню</div>
  
  <ul>
    <li class="r1">
      <a href="" title="">Первое меню</a>
    </li>
    <li class="r2">
      <a href="" title="">новое меню и интересное и просто проверка</a>
    </li>
    <li class="r3">
      <a href="" title="">Тестовое меню</a>
    </li>
    <li class="r4">
      <a href="" title="">Главная</a>
    </li> 
  </ul>
  
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

используйте :before для иконок

Comment: А зачем вы копируете ответ ниже?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте псевдоэлементы для позиционирования иконок спрайта:

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.circle {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle-img {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;   
}
.circle-img:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin: -7.5px 0 0 -7.5px;
    background-image: url(img/sprites.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
.circle-img.yellow:before {    
    background-color: orange;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.circle-img.green:before {    
    background-color: green;
    background-position: 0 15px;
}
.circle-img.red:before {    
    background-color: red;
    background-position: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <a href="#" class="circle-img yellow"></a>
    <a href="#" class="circle-img green"></a>
    <a href="#" class="circle-img red"></a>
</div>
```